# save images into database

Tags: android, database

i want to retrieve contacts and images and show them into list view and save images and contacts into database, in another activity i want to retrieve contacts from database with images and show them into list view i m able retrieve contacts but how to save images into database and after that how to retrieve images from database

i using this method to save data into database

```
public void addBlockedNumberWithImage(String number, String name,
        byte[] image) {

    // Add a new blocked number
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BLOCKLIST_NUMBER, number);
    values.put(BLOCKLIST_NAME, name);
    values.put(CONTACT_IMAGE, image);

    /* Inserting the entry */
    db.insert(TABLE_BLOCKLISTWITHIMAGE, null, values);
    db.close(); // close the database connection
}



DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
db.addBlockedNumberWithImage(phoneNumber, name, image);
```

Comment: You can store the path/uri of image in database with contact no. after retrieving contact no. and path you can access image from path

Comment: storing images to database is bad practice. Rather store images on sdcard and store only this path in database.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of saving the images into a database, I'd instead save the images to somewhere on the device (preferably the SD card), and in the database save the location of each image

Then when you want to display them, you can simply retrieve the path to the image from the database, and load it up :)

Answer (score 0):

In my application i am uploading an image from gallery and the image which i uploaded want to store in database.But how to store bitmap in database i am converting bitmap to string and saving in database.

Imageupload.class:

```
public class Imageupload12 extends Activity {
Button buttonLoadImage;
ImageView targetImage;
int i=0;
Database database=new Database(this);
String i1;
String img;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main5);
buttonLoadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadimage);
targetImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.targetimage);

Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!=null)
{
img=b.getString("image");
targetImage2.setImageURI("image");
//i am getting error as i cant assign string to imageview.

}

buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
Log.i("photo",""+intent);
startActivityForResult(intent, i);
i=i+1;
}});

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
switch(requestCode) {

case 0:
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
Uri targetUri = data.getData();
// textTargetUri.setText(targetUri.toString());
Bitmap bitmap;
try {
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

i1=bitmap.toString();
Log.i("firstimage........",""+i1);
targetImage.setVisibility(0);

SQLiteDatabase db=database.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO UPLOAD VALUES('"+i1+"');");

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
break;

}

}
}
```

Image.class:

```
public class Image extends Activity {
Database database=new Database(this);
static EfficientAdapter adapter, adapter1;
static ListView lv1;

static SQLiteDatabase db;
static EfficientAdapter adp;
static Cursor c1;

static Vector<String>IMAGE=new Vector<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

db=database.getReadableDatabase();
c1=db.rawQuery("select * from UPLOAD;", null);

if (c1.moveToFirst()) {

do {
IMAGE.add(c1.getString(0).toString());

} while (c1.moveToNext());

c1.close();
}

lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.List);

adapter=new EfficientAdapter(this);

lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

ImageView add=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imv1a);

add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
IMAGE.clear();

Intent i=new Intent(Image.this,Imageupload12.class);
startActivity(i);

}
});

}

private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

// protected final Context Context = null;
protected LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
AlertDialog.Builder aBuilder;
public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
mLayoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

return IMAGE.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

final ViewHolder mVHolder;
if(convertView == null){
convertView=mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pjtlistdetails, parent, false);

mVHolder=new ViewHolder();

mVHolder.t1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pjtdetails);
mVHolder.time=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

mVHolder.imv=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editic);
mVHolder.imvd=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
mVHolder.imvf=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fwd);

mVHolder.imv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

String img=IMAGE.elementAt(position);
Log.i("image...",""+img);

Context ctx=v.getContext();
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
ctx = v.getContext();
myIntent.setClass(ctx, Imageupload12.class);
myIntent.putExtra("image", img);

ctx.startActivity(myIntent);

IMAGE.clear();

}
});
static class ViewHolder{

ImageButton imv;
ImageView imvd,imvf;
}
```

to retrieve a image from db

```
public Bitmap getImage(int i){

String qu = "select img from table where feedid=" + i ;
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(qu, null);

if (cur.moveToFirst()){
byte[] imgByte = cur.getBlob(0);
cur.close();
return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);
}
if (cur != null && !cur.isClosed()) {
cur.close();
}

return null ;
}
```

Its a very old code check if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Base64](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) class, you can encode a bitmap into string and then store it to database.

The following sample code could be used:

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg =get bitmap from image;

ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();

String ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
```

Now decode this string to use image.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to store and retrieve image from database using `SQLiteOpenHelper` class

```
package com.aliahmad.store_retrive_image;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DataManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    public final static String tab="image";
    public final static String col1="iname";
    public final static String col2="id";
    public DataManager(Context context)
    {
        super(context, "MyData", null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL("create table image (iname text,id blob)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(DataManager.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "+oldVersion+" to"+newVersion+", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+tab);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

when store button clicked call this function

```
public void onStore(View v)
{
    try
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //image is object of Bitmap that you want to store
        image.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] data=baos.toByteArray();
        SQLiteDatabase db=new DataManager(this).getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DataManager.col1, et.getText().toString());
        cv.put(DataManager.col2, data);
        db.insert(DataManager.tab, null, cv);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Errro - "+e,1 ).show();
    }       
}
```

to retrieve the image call this function

```
public void onRet(View v)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=new DataManager(this).getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cr=db.query(DataManager.tab, new String[]{DataManager.col2}, DataManager.col1+"= ?", new String[]{str[which]}, null, null, null);
    if(cr.moveToFirst())
    {
        byte [] b=cr.getBlob(4);
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(b); 
        image= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        iv.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "not found", 1).show();
    }
    db.close();
}
```